# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.unbescape.uri.UriEscape

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I get this error when ever I try to load this web page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
    <title>Competition</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    
      <p th:text="'Name: ' + ${competition.name}" />
      <p th:text="'Date: ' + ${competition.date}" />
      <p th:text="'Venue: ' + ${competition.Venue}" />
      <div th:if="${competition.competitors != null}">
      <h3>Competitors</h3>
      <ul>
        <li th:each="item : ${competition.competitors}" th:text="${item}"></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
       <h4>Add Competitor.</h4>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/competitions/{id}(id=${competition.id})}" th:object="${email}" method="post">
     
        <p>User email: <input type="text" th:field="*{text}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
      
    </div>
     <p th:text="${competition.id}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the org.unbescape dependency to my pom.xml.

I started getting this error when I added the the URL to the form
(This line:)

> th:action="@{/competitions/{id}(id=${competition.id})}"

Comment: Please post a snipit of the stack trace

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: Your complete exception there should be a whole list of classes it went through before you got the ClassNotFound exception

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a older version of `org.unbescape`. The class `UriEscape` was introduced in versin 1.1.0. Ref [here](https://github.com/unbescape/unbescape/blob/master/src/main/java/org/unbescape/uri/UriEscape.java)

Can you try by upgrading the `org.unbescape` version to 1.1.1 as follows?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.unbescape</groupId>
    <artifactId>unbescape</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```